# Getting timeout error for min_sub_array_sum?

Tags: dynamic-programming, sub-array

I am getting this kind of weird error, I wrote a function to find the minimum sub array sum. But this doesn't work when the values of array start from 1 to size for value 1 2 3 4. I get timeout, but same code for 1 2 3 4 5 gives the correct answer. If I put a statement print statement above min_sub_array it gives the right answer for all values. It also works fine when the values start from 0 to size - 1

```
int min_sub_array_sum(int d[], int size)
{
    for(int i = 1; i <= size; i++)
        d[i] = -d[i];

    int max_end_i = d[1], max_so_far = d[1];

    for(int i = 2; i <= size; i++)
    {
        max_end_i += d[i];

        if(max_so_far < max_end_i)
            max_so_far = max_end_i;

        if(max_end_i < 0)
            max_end_i = 0;
    }

    return (-max_so_far);
}

int main()
{
    int t;
    cin>>t;

    while(t--)
    {
        int n;
        cin>>n;

        int d[n];

        for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
            cin>>d[i];


        cout<<min_sub_array_sum(d, n)<<'\n';

    }
}
```

I should get the value of 1 for 1 2 3 4. But I am not getting.

Answer (score 1):

You are accessing the **nth** index of array **d[n]** which does not exist.